# excel vba, find a range

Tags: excel, vba

In excel, everyday i have to find where "spot" in the cell and then select after this row befor the cell containing "public".

can any one help me How to find rows contains "spot" and end selection before containing cell "public".

Comment: Does your sheet look like this?
* spot
* spot
* spot
* public

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a homework assignment :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. looks very much like a homework assignment...

Here's a hint -

> First search for the word spot, note
>   the row number, then search for the
>   word public then not the row number
>   and then select the rows between

Hope this helps :)

Cheers... Nilesh